# Cannot understand error:

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, runtime-error

```
SELECT 
   CAST(dbo.TrnRisk.VehDriverName AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClientID AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.FileNo AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClaimNo AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.NameInitials AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.LossDate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.MstInsurer.ABSAInsurerName AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.AgentID + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstAgent.AgentName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS AgentIDName 
 , CAST(dbo.VieTeamSelect.SubRegionID + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.VieTeamSelect.SubRegionName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS SubRegionIDName
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.TeamID + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.VieTeamSelect.TeamName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS TeamIDName
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.LinkID + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstLink.LinkName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS LinkIDName
 , CAST(dbo.TrnPolicy.BrokerContact + ' ' + ISNULL(MstHandler.BrokerName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS BrokerIDName
 , CAST(ISNULL(dbo.VieClaimRegister.AssessorID,'None') + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstClaimAssessors.AssesorID,'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS AssessorIDName
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.OwnDamage AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ThirdParty AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ThirdPartyEstimate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.Paid AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.Estimate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.OwnDamageEstimate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.SubSection AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.DriverAge AS VARCHAR(100))

 -- RiskCoverDays looks at first item on risk table in order to get risk inception date.
 -- If there are multiple items then we only look at the earliest risk inception date.
 -- Not quite correct, but a big improvement over the old Access database and
 -- easy enough to program ...

 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.RiskDeletion AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ReportDate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.CauseID AS VARCHAR(100))

 -- Make/ model description without Mead & McGrouther code:

 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.VehModel AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClientStatusCode AS VARCHAR(100))

 -- The following are intended to be outside the printable area in the spreadsheet:

 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.SectionID AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.RiskNo AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.LossDate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.TrnPolicy.InceptionDate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.DateLoaded AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ReportDate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.SettledDate  AS VARCHAR(100))

 -- How many weeks from the load date to the report date as per F1:

 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.SettledDate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.LossDate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClaimPostalID AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.FastTrack AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ExGratia AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.HandlerID + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstHandler.BrokerName,'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS HandlerIDName
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.K4K AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.Registration AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClaimsLinkID AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.MstUser.UserName AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ClaimsLinkName
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.Repudiation AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.InsurerID AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.Fees AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.Expenses AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.Recoveries AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.Salvages AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.RecoveriesEstimate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.SalvagesEstimate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(ISNULL(ThirdPartyEstimate,0)AS VARCHAR(100)) AS EstimateThirdParty
 , CAST(ISNULL(dbo.VieEstimateMovement.EstimateMovement,0)AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ClaimMovement
 , CAST(VieClaimRegister.AuthorisedDate AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(VieClaimRegister.TeamID AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(VieClaimRegister.AgentID AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(VieClaimRegister.LinkID AS VARCHAR(100))
 , CAST(VieClaimRegister.InsurerID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS InsurerIDForFilter

 -- How many days from the load date to the authorised date(claim turn around time)

 , Cast(MstProduct.BusinessArea AS VARCHAR(100))


 FROM dbo.VieClaimRegister

 LEFT  JOIN dbo.MstUser ON 
    dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClaimsLinkID = dbo.MstUser.UserID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.TrnClient ON
dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClientID = dbo.TrnClient.ClientID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.TrnPolicy ON 
dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClientID = dbo.TrnPolicy.ClientID
AND dbo.VieClaimRegister.FileNo = dbo.TrnPolicy.FileNo
 LEFT JOIN dbo.VieEstimateMovement On
dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClientID = dbo.VieEstimateMovement.ClientID
AND dbo.VieClaimRegister.FileNo = dbo.VieEstimateMovement.FileNo
AND dbo.VieClaimRegister.ClaimNo = dbo.VieEstimateMovement.ClaimNo


 -- VieTeamSelect includes MstTeam, MstSubRegion, MstRegion, MstCompany:

 LEFT JOIN dbo.VieTeamSelect ON 
dbo.VieClaimRegister.TeamID = dbo.VieTeamSelect.TeamID

 -- Link code is as per claim table, not policy table (!) :

 LEFT JOIN dbo.MstLink ON 
dbo.VieClaimRegister.LinkID = dbo.MstLink.LinkID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.MstAgent ON 
dbo.VieClaimRegister.AgentID = dbo.MstAgent.AgentID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.MstInsurer ON

 -- Insurer code is as per claim table, not policy table (!) :

dbo.VieClaimRegister.InsurerID = dbo.MstInsurer.InsurerID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.MstInsurer MstInsurerLead ON

 -- Insurer code is as per claim table, not policy table (!) :

dbo.VieClaimRegister.InsurerID = MstInsurerLead.InsurerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TrnRisk ON 
VieClaimRegister.ClientID = TrnRisk.ClientIDo
AND VieClaimRegister.FileNo = TrnRisk.FileNo 
AND VieClaimRegister.RiskNo = TrnRisk.RiskID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MstHandler ON 
VieClaimRegister.HandlerID = dbo.MstHandler.BrokerID 
AND TrnPolicy.BrokerContact = MstHandler.BrokerID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MstClaimAssessors ON 
dbo.VieClaimRegister.AssessorID = dbo.MstClaimAssessors.AssesorID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.MstProduct ON 
dbo.TrnPolicy.ProductID= dbo.MstProduct.ProductID
```

---

This is an SQL query to access a set of data for use in  Reporting services. However it is giving me an error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Absa Insurance and Financial Advisers (Pty) Limited' to data type int." even after Casting everything to a Varchar. I am still new to SQL so any help will be greatly appreciated. Sorry that its so long, there is a lot of data to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you need to cast the ID values in these statements to varchar:

```
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.AgentID + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstAgent.AgentName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS AgentIDName 
 , CAST(dbo.VieTeamSelect.SubRegionID + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.VieTeamSelect.SubRegionName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS SubRegionIDName
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.TeamID + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.VieTeamSelect.TeamName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS TeamIDName
 , CAST(dbo.VieClaimRegister.LinkID + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstLink.LinkName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS LinkIDName
 , CAST(dbo.TrnPolicy.BrokerContact + ' ' + ISNULL(MstHandler.BrokerName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS BrokerIDName
 , CAST(ISNULL(dbo.VieClaimRegister.AssessorID,'None') + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstClaimAssessors.AssesorID,'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS AssessorIDName
```

Meaning you need something like this:

```
 , CAST(Cast(dbo.VieClaimRegister.AgentID as varchar(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstAgent.AgentName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS AgentIDName 
 , CAST(Cast(dbo.VieTeamSelect.SubRegionID as varchar(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.VieTeamSelect.SubRegionName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS SubRegionIDName
 , CAST(Cast(dbo.VieClaimRegister.TeamID as varchar(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.VieTeamSelect.TeamName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS TeamIDName
 , CAST(Cast(dbo.VieClaimRegister.LinkID as varchar(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstLink.LinkName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS LinkIDName
 , CAST(Cast(dbo.TrnPolicy.BrokerContact as varchar(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(MstHandler.BrokerName, 'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS BrokerIDName
 , CAST(ISNULL(Cast(dbo.VieClaimRegister.AssessorID as varchar(10)),'None') + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstClaimAssessors.AssesorID,'Unknown')AS VARCHAR(100)) AS AssessorIDName
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the numbers to varchar when you want to concatenate them with a varchar, otherwise it will try to convert the varchar to a number to make it an addition.